# Synchronic code with map functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I think I got totally lost, I thought I had at least some grasp on async stuff, but this particular case got me confused.

I perform a search on the database and expect an array of results.
Then i map through the array, check for flag and push info to the array.

However, I'm doing async calls wrong, because when I console log the finalData it's always empty, therefore it resolves before it should.

Here are my attempts, tried it both ways:

```
let finalData = [];

let lastWeek = new Date();
lastWeek.setDate(lastWeek.getDate() - 7);

db.find({ createdAt: { "$gte": lastWeek } }).then((records, err) => {

    async function test() {
        let array = _.map(records, (record) => {
            db2.find({ 'foo': record.id }).then((bar, err) => {

                if (bar.endDate) {
                    let data = `Email: ${record.email}`;
                    finalData.push(data);
                } else {
                    let data = `Email: ${record.email}`;
                    finalData.push(data);
                }
            });
        });

        await Promise.all(array).then(() => {
            console.log(finalData);
        });

    }

    test();
});
```

and:

```
db.find({ createdAt: { "$gte": lastWeek } }).then((records, err) => {

    let promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        _.map(records, (record) => {
            db2.find({ 'foo': record.id }).then((bar, err) => {

                if (bar.endDate) {
                    let data = `Email: ${record.email}`;
                    finalData.push(data);
                } else {
                    let data = `Email: ${record.email}`;
                    finalData.push(data);
                }
            });
        });

        resolve();
    });

    promise1.then(() => {
        console.log(finalData);
    })
});
```

Results are the same, I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Just a note on `map` ... in this case you should use `forEach` or simple `for loop` since there is no real need for `map` if you do not return anything from it.

Comment: db.find() is async. You need to await on it.

Comment: Ah, that is correct, initially I intended to return something but ended up not doing it, will change that, thanks

Comment: @Akrion You cannot use `forEach` with asynchronous functions

Comment: @Bergi good call. I was thinking something among the lines of `for..of`.

Answer (score 1):

- Your basic attempt looks fine, you just forgot to `return` the promises from your `map` callback so that `array` was actually an array of `undefined` values, not of promises
- You don't need that `finalData` array to manually `push` to. Just resolve your promises with the respective value, and `Promise.all` will collect them into an array of results anyway
- A `then` callback doesn't take a second `err` parameter - if your function returns a promise already, it *either* calls a fulfillment callback or a rejection callback.
- Don't mix `then` and `async`/`await` style

```
let lastWeek = new Date();
lastWeek.setDate(lastWeek.getDate() - 7);

const records = await db.find({ createdAt: { "$gte": lastWeek } });
let promises = records.map(async (record) => {
    const bar = await db2.find({ 'foo': record.id });
    if (bar.endDate) {
        return `Email: ${record.email}`;
    } else {
        return `Email: ${record.email}`;
    }
});

const finalData = await Promise.all(promises)
console.log(finalData);
```

Or alternatively:

```
let lastWeek = new Date();
lastWeek.setDate(lastWeek.getDate() - 7);

return db.find({ createdAt: { "$gte": lastWeek } }).then(records => {
    let promises = records.map(record => {
        return db2.find({ 'foo': record.id }).then(bar => {
//      ^^^^^^
            if (bar.endDate) {
                return `Email: ${record.email}`;
//              ^^^^^^
            } else {
                return `Email: ${record.email}`;
//              ^^^^^^
            }
        });
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
//  ^^^^^^
}).then(finalData => {
    console.log(finalData);
});
```

Comment: That looks like something that actually might work, when I'm back on PC I'll check this solution out and accept the answer if everything goes smoothly. Thank you!